# using Jade - need a makefile command to compile source Jade to Public directory and maintain source directory structure

Tags: makefile, pug

(Disclaimer: I am a UX designer, and this is my first "self made" makefile)

I would like to add to my makefile a line to take the contents of my src/jade directory and output it as html in public/. My makefile is in a dir above both of those in a project dir that contains both src and public. So what I want is:

```
src/jade
  |--Enterprise/index.jade
  |--SmallBusines/index.jade
  |--Public Sector/index.jade
```

And get

```
public
  |--Enterprise/index.jade
  |--SmallBusines/index.jade
  |--Public Sector/index.jade
```

What I can't figure out is how to have it crawl the subdirectories in src/jade. Here is what I have:

```
jade -P -p . -o public src/jade/
```

This just takes thing in src/jade but no subdirs. I've experimented and Googled quite a bit, but nothing quite does it.

EDIT:
Here's my actual makefile

```
all: 
  mkdir -p public
  make jade
  make coffee
  make less
  make statics

jade: 
  jade -P -p . -o public src/jade/

coffee: 
  coffee --compile --output public/js src/coffee

less: 
  lessc --strict-imports src/less/styles.less public/css/styles.css

statics:
  cp -a src/less/img public/css/
  cp -a src/font public/
  cp -a src/coffee/bootstrap.min.js public/js/

clean:
  rm -rf public
```

Also - once I figure it out, I will need to exclude directories too since the src/jade will have things like /includes and /blocks that are imported into the actual "pages" of the site but not pages themselves.

I've done the jade --help, and there's nothing in there about subdirectories and exclusions, as well as man make. Are there any other places I could look, or has anyone ran in to this before?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about jade, but if it takes a single `.jade` file and generates a single `.html` file, then you probably want something like this:

```
JADE := jade
JADEFLAGS := -P -p .
SRCDIR := src/jade
HTMLDIR := public

JADEFILES := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -type f -name \*.jade)
HTMLFILES := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(HTMLDIR)/%,$(JADEFILES))

.PHONY: all
all: $(HTMLFILES)

$(HTMLDIR)/%.html : $(SRCDIR)/%.jade
        $(JADE) $(JADEFLAGS) -o $(HTMLDIR) $<
```

If you do it the way you were doing it before, then all your output files will be created every time you run make, regardless of what's changed.  If that's all you want to do, then using make is simply useless complication.  Make is for avoiding unnecessary rebuilds, based on when files have changed; if you want rebuild everything all the time whenever you run the command, just write a shell script, not a makefile.

ETA:

If you really just want the simplest version, try this (again, I've never used jade so I'm not sure how it works, but if it takes a list of jade files this should work):

```
# Use the UNIX find(1) command to locate all the jade files under src/jade
jade:
        jade -P -p . -o public `find src/jade -name \*.jade`
```

ETA:

It seems your example output is wrong: it shows that jade will generate files like `foo.jade`, but that's not right: jade appears to generate files like `foo.html`.  If jade doesn't maintain the directory structure itself, then you'll need something much closer to my original suggestion.  I'll try to simplify it a bit:

```
SRCDIR := src/jade
HTMLDIR := public

# Find all the .jade files, using UNIX find(1)
JADEFILES := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -type f -name \*.jade)

# Convert all the .jade files to .html in the output directory
HTMLFILES := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.jade,$(HTMLDIR)/%.html,$(JADEFILES))

# A target that depends on all the .html files we will generate
.PHONY: jade
jade: $(HTMLFILES)

# A pattern rule that shows how to build a single .jade file
# into a single .html file
$(HTMLDIR)/%.html : $(SRCDIR)/%.jade
        jade -P -p . -o $(@D) $<
```

To learn about the pattern rule you should read the GNU make manual section on "Automatic Variables", but basically `$<` stands in for the first prerequisite (the .jade file in this case) and `$@` is the target file (the .html file in this case).  The variable `$(@D)` is the directory of the target file.

Comment: The makefile I have right now I added to the original question. It's set up that I can just compile one type of thing at a time.

Honestly, I am not even sure I know how to read the answer. Maybe I should find someone here in-person to explain it? I can try to replace the variables and run it, see what happens though.

Comment: It still seems not so useful to turn this into a makefile.  A shell script that took an argument and ran the command would be easier (assuming you know how to write a shell script) and it would not require you learning how to use make.  You're not actually using any of the advantages of make, here.  However I'll edit my answer to be simpler.

Comment: That new command does work, it just doesn't maintain the directories. It finds all the jade files, and outputs them to public. Maybe jade doesn't do this, since I can't actually run a compile that excludes nested files. As a web templating engine though, you think it would. Oh, and I have no experience with shell scripts, or any scripts. I normally build everything using Codekit, which is a GUI for all jade/less/coffee etc. (also FYI I don't have enough rep here to upvote anyone or I would).

Comment: If jade works as you say (doesn't maintain the directory structure) then you want something closer to my original suggestion.  That suggestion will run jade one time for each .jade file, and you can use that to call it with the -o flag that tells it to place the output in the proper directory.  I'll edit again.

Answer (score 1):

Since I use Jade with Node in many projects, I made a simple (albeit not so smart) script that crawls the jade folders and outputs the structure to a destination folder. Since I used this in a couple of projects, I input the source and destination folders though the CLI. The coffeescript code follows:

```
fs = require 'fs'
path = require 'path'
exec = require('child_process').exec

# Get base from cli
jadePath = process.argv[2]
base = process.argv[3]

_build = (dir) ->
  files = fs.readdirSync dir
  for f in files

    if f == path.basename __filename
      continue

    fullPath = path.join(dir, f)
    stat = fs.statSync fullPath

    if stat.isDirectory()
      try
        fs.mkdirSync path.join(base, fullPath)
      _build fullPath
    else if path.extname(f) == '.jade'
      # Compile jade
      dirName = path.join base, (path.dirname fullPath)
      dirName = dirName.replace jadePath, ''
      dirName = dirName.replace '//', '/'
      console.log "Compiling jade file '#{fullPath}' to directory #{dirName}"
      exec('jade -o ' + dirName + ' ' + fullPath)

# Start process with path from cli
_build jadePath
```

As a side note, a usually build/automate my projects using npm directly, through the `scripts` session in `packages.json`. For example:

```
"scripts": {
    "build:js": "coffee -cb -o www/js/ www/_src/coffee/",
    "build:html": "coffee run_jade.coffee www/_src/jade/ www/templates/",
    "build:css": "sass www/_src/sass/style.scss www/css/style.css",
    "build": "npm run build:js && npm run build:html && npm run build:css",
    "watch": "watch 'npm run build' www/_src/",
    "test": "karma start test/karma.conf.coffee"
  }
```

and then if I want to build my html, I can simply `npm run build:html`. Hope this helps :)